# Solutions to the equation $\langle z,u_1\rangle \langle z,u_2\rangle =\langle u_1,u_2\rangle$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, inner-products

Suppose $u_1$ and $u_2$ are elements of $\mathbb{C}^N$ of norm $1$, and that $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\not =0$.  If $z$ is in $\mathbb{B}_N$ (the unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^N$), how many solutions does the equation  $\langle z,u_1\rangle \langle z,u_2\rangle =\langle u_1,u_2\rangle $
have in $\mathbb{B}_N$?

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the answer when $\big|\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\big|=1$ is that there are no solutions in $\mathbb{B}_N$.  I am not sure how to proceed when $0<\big|\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\big|<1$.

Thank you.

Comment: After a unitary transformation, you can assume that $u_1 = e_1$ and $u_2 = a\cdot e_1 + b\cdot e_2$ with $\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2 = 1$ (the case $N = 1$ is clear).

Comment: If $z=z_1e_1+\cdots +z_Ne_N$, then the equation becomes $z_1(z_1\overline{a}+z_2\overline{b})=\overline{a}$.  Solving for $z_2$, we get $z_2=\frac{\overline{a}(1-z_1^2)}{\overline{b}z_1}$. Since $\lim_{z_1\rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{a}(1-z_1^2)}{\overline{b}z_1}=0$, there are infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{B}_N$.

Comment: The limit as $z_1\to 0$ isn't $0$. The numerator tends to $\overline{a}$ and the denominator to $0$, so the quotient tends to $\infty$. Did you mean $\lim_{z_1\to 1}$? Since holomorphic functions in dimension $> 1$ don't have isolated zeros, if there is one solution, there are infinitely many.